# How to get value from json type response in Laravel5

Tags: php, json, laravel

Here is a function return:

```
return response()->json(['aa'=>'bbb']);
```

and i print the function response ,the result like this:

```
JsonResponse {#186
 #jsonOptions: 0
 #data: "{"aa":"bbb"}"
 #callback: null
 #encodingOptions: 15
 +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#187
 #computedCacheControl: array:1 [
  "no-cache" => true
]
```

i have never seen it before,how can i get the value `bbb` ? thanks

Comment: the json is a function return, i want to get the json in the controller,and not in the js script

Comment: in normal, the function return is like this return json_encode(['aa'=>'bbb']);
and,i get the value bbb like this: $result = json_decode($function_return);
$result['aa']. but it doesn't work in above

Comment: If you just want the json string the use `json_encode(...)`

Comment: i tried json_encode($function_return). and the result is null

Comment: No instead of `response()->json(['aa' => 'bbb'])` use `json_encode(['aa' => 'bbb'])`. `response()` is if you want to send a HTTP response to the browser.

Comment: can you show us some code of how you'd **like** to access the object? We can show you how it is possible.

Comment: $output = response()->json(['username'=>'John Doe']);  
echo $output->getData()->username;

Answer (score 30, accepted):

i have resolved the question,use `getData()` can read the json.

```
$a = response()->json(['aa'=>'bbb']);  
$a->getData()->aa;
```

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 5):

What you see is the object that `response()->json()` produces. That's not actually what the client will get. Because Laravel will convert it into a string before sending it back.

On the client you can just use it as JSON. Here's an example with jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your/route'
}).done(function(data){
    alert(data.aa);  // alerts bbb
});
```

Comment: i just want to get the value as the function result.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what guanyue said:

```
$a = response()->json(['aa'=>'bbb'])->getData();  
dd($a->aa);
```

Its work!